# common layout page trigger all pages vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vuex4

AppTopbar.vue

```
<Dropdown v-model="selected" :options="storesLists" @change="onChange" 
optionLabel="name" :filter="true" />
```

```
 onChange(event) {
        console.log(event.value.value);
         localStorage.setItem('shopid'); 
         
        
         }
    },
```

Products.vue

```
import { useLayout } from '@/layout/composables/layout';


<template>
</template>
```

AppTopbar is common layout of all pages.
when i click onchange AppTopbar.vue is only affectet AppTopbar page only.
but i want to if onchange AppTopbar.vue to triger Products.vue and all pages also

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a store: https://pinia.vuejs.org/

Set the value in the store and it is available everywhere.